# nginx docker proxy_path to an other docker in the server

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have these two dockers runs on y server:

`docker-registry:5000/library/nginx:1.7.10.1` which ports are `443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3010->80/tcp`

`docker-registry:5000/library/java:8-jre` which ports are `0.0.0.0:9090->8080/tcp`

what I wanna do is to response all requests to the Nginx server which starts with `/api/` to the java docker. So, I used a config file for my Nginx docker like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /opt/www;
    server_name localhost some_ip_address some_other_ip_address ;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types
        application/octet-stream
        application/atom+xml
        application/x-javascript
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/x-component;

    location ~ ^/(api)/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://simorgh-java:8080;
    }
}
```

But when I send send a request from my browser to my the Nginx server containing `/api/` in URL (like `http://path_to_my_server:3010/api/login`) I get 404 Not Found response.

Is there any thing wrong in my config file? Do I basically use wrong solution? What should I do to resolve that?

The reason to that (having a proxy path to java server via nginx server) is I just have one port which is open on my server and all requests should be received via that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check see if they are linked together or not, by default they cannot see each other.

`docker inspect <your container> | grep Links`

you can either use rewrite in nginx

[Create Temporary and Permanent Redirects with Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx)